# Group By 2 Columns with similar info to link with a 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have **two columns** with similar info:

column 1 = item 1, item 3, item 5
column 3 = item 3, item 5, item 8

I want to display how many of each item are in total from both columns.

I have this:

---

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT FirstTypeID, SecondTypeID, ThirdTypeID, DesignID, COUNT(DesignID) FROM designs WHERE Approved = '1' GROUP BY FirstTypeID, SecondTypeID, ThirdTypeID");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $DesignID = stripslashes($row['DesignID']);
    $FirstTypeID = stripslashes($row['FirstTypeID']);
    $SecondTypeID = stripslashes($row['SecondTypeID']);
    $ThirdTypeID = stripslashes($row['ThirdTypeID']);
    $Total = stripslashes($row['COUNT(DesignID)']);
}

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE TypeID = '$FirstTypeID' OR TypeID = '$SecondTypeID' OR TypeID = '$ThirdTypeID'");
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "<li><a href='index_type.php?TypeID=".$row2{'TypeID'}."'>".$row2{'TypeName'}." (" . $Total . ")</a></li>";
}
```

---

but I'm not getting the result that I want, it's only giving me results from one column.

Comment: Please give use more information, what is column1 and what is column2 in your case, what are the expected outputs and what do you get instead?

Comment: Is `FirstMonoID` correct? Everywhere else you refer to `FirstTypeID`. Also, you don't `select` the `DesignID` field so `$DesignID` will always be NULL.

Comment: I'm sorry...Column 1 and Column 2 are the 2 columns from the table i'm doing the query. The items are the values on each column and the output i'm looking for in this case would be something like: Item 1(1), Item3(2), Item5(2), Item8(1)

Comment: @AlejandroGuzman you should add this information to your question

Comment: Alejandro, you still did not answer my questions. How can I know which is column 1 and which is column 2 if you do not specify that? Also, you still didn't specify what is the expected output and what is the real output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for but well here it is

```
$typesIDs = array(type0 => "", type1 => "", type2 => ""...);

foreach($typesID as $index=>$value){
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM designs COLUMN1 = ".$index." OR COLUMN2 = ".$index;
   $sql = mysql_query($query);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
   array[$index] => $row["total"]
}
```